# Как сменить расширение у файла?

Tags: delphi

Как сменить расширение у файла?
пробовал так:

```
ChangeFileExt('1.php', '.jpg');
```

и так:

```
 RenameFile('1.php', '1.jpg')
```

в обоих случая результата никакого

Answer (score 3):

[[@Никола Кривошея](/users/5620/%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%8F)](/users/5620/%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%8F), первый случай никак не связан с взаимодействием с файловой системой, хотя имя сигнатуры функции "говорит", будто это так. На самом деле ничего подобного, данная функция лишь возвращает строку-"путь к файлу" с измененным расширением, указанным во втором параметре. А вот вторая функция уже имеет прямое отношение к файловой системе Windows. Она, как говорит ее имя, переименовывает файл. И она, кстати, у меня работает:

```
RenameFile('C:\coc3.js','C:\coc3.txt');
```

У вас функция может не работать, например, из-за того, что ваша программа не обладает правами доступа к этому файлу( права на переименование, удаление и т.д ). Скорее всего мешает UAC, ну или вы просто не указываете полный путь к файлу.

Answer (score -1):

RenameFile - это функция.

http://www.delphisources.ru/pages/faq/faq_delphi_basics/RenameFile.php.html